# Check other column if a column is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following table, where `order_date` and `delivery_date` is of type 'varchar'

```
id      name        order_date      delivery_date
---------------------------------------------------------
1       A           04/01/2017      04/08/2017
2       B           04/01/2017      NULL
3       C           04/02/2017      04/03/2017
4       D           04/04/2017      04/05/2017
5       E           04/05/2017      04/11/2017
6       F           04/11/2017      NULL
7       G           04/15/2017      04/17/2017
8       H           04/18/2017      NULL
```

I need all the records which have

```
* delivery_date between 04/01/2017 TO 04/15/2017
* if delivery_date IS NULL then check order_date between 04/01/2017 TO 04/15/2017
    (in this case order_date is assumed as delivery_date)
```

I'm trying this code :

```
SELECT *,
IF(delivery_date IS NOT NULL, `delivery_date`, `order_date`) as `final_date`
FROM `test` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`final_date` ,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2017','%m/%d/%Y')
```

But is is giving this error :

```
Unknown column 'final_date' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: #1: Use `COALESCE(delivery_date, order_date)` instead which is Standrad SQL. #2: Repeat the calculation in `WHERE` as you can't use an alias here

Comment: simple rule you can't use alias in where clause.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the column alias in `WHERE` which is not allowed. You will have to use the entire below expression

```
IF(delivery_date IS NOT NULL, `delivery_date`, `order_date`)
```

Your `WHERE` clause should looks like

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(COALESCE(`delivery_date`, `order_date`) ,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2017','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul. Now I'm trying this code now :
`SELECT * FROM test
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(COALESCE(discharge_date, admit_date) ,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y')  AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2017','%m/%d/%Y')`

And I get the following result : 1,3,4,5 but I expect 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
IF(delivery_date IS NOT NULL, `delivery_date`, `order_date`) as `final_date`
FROM `test` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(IFNULL(`delivery_date`,`final_date`) ,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2017','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Try above code.Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the query with the help of sample provide by @Rahul and @Sagar Gangwal. The query is :

```
SELECT * FROM `test`  
WHERE 
    STR_TO_DATE( COALESCE(NULLIF(`delivery_date`,''),`order_date`) ,'%m/%d/%Y') 
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('04/01/2017','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('04/15/2017','%m/%d/%Y') ";
```